# Html 5 Video angular 5

Tags: .net, html, angular, video

I am making an angular app to play video from my local folders , previously it was working fine when I was doing with nodejs but when I switched to .net with the same angular code it gives me error.

CODE:

```
<video width="500" src = "../../../../VideoList/orm/ORM.mp4" controls #video1>
    </video>
```

ERROR:
     GET http://localhost:62416/VideoList/orm/ORM.mp4 404 (Not Found)

I do not know why. file path is correct but still it gives me the same error.
plz help

Comment: are you sure the file path is correct? if you type that in the browser (http://localhost:62416/../../../../VideoList/orm/ORM.mp4 does it give you the file? also, have you configured a MIME type for your server to handle mp4 (video/mp4)

Comment: No I did not configure the mime type..? can you plz tell me how to configure it or if you can share any documentation link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make sure that your server has a MIME type of video/mp4 for your video.

in IIS you can adjust that either with a web.config file, or:

- Right-click the site in IIS and select Properties.
- Select the HTTP Headers Tab.
- Select File Types.
- Under the MIME Map section, select New Type.
- Type ".mp4" as the associated extension and "video/mp4" as the content type.
- Click OK.